# Layout is crashing after multiple rotations

Tags: bug, android-app

I used the app, and after I finished I moved through the room with my smartphone in my hand, without locking the screen. Because of my hand movement, the screen rotates multiple times from landscape to portrait and back. After that, I looked at the app, and the layout was completely crashed (Screenshot attached). 
If I pressed a button, everything was fine and the layout re-order back.

[image: crashed layout]

Edit: my device is a Nexus 5 with Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, as vigorously as I tried. You might want to include your device model and Android version.

Comment: Ugh, you forgot to include the app version. I also have Nexus 5 on Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.82 (beta), and I can't repro this. Even after tapping achievement button.

Comment: Sorry, stack exchange version is 1.0.77. I know, very crazy problem. I was very confused when I seen it

Comment: Actually you don't need to mention Nexus. When we see low battery, we know *it is* Nexus

Comment: I see this all the time - probably on a weekly basis - but never went to the trouble to figure out how to repro it.

Comment: Oh, I have the same heisenbug in my application(which is supposed to be used by many angry people), I was depressed and then I saw this inspiring post! P.S. Anyway I think, I'll just add some code that checks that only one frame is visible. P.P.S. also the same thing occurs if you use replace without commit(which clears backstack) and replace the root frame.

Comment: Dupplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271580/android-app-1-0-77-has-a-multi-view-transparency-bug#comment881153_271580

Comment: I think this should be a question for `stackexchange meta` and not for `stackoverflow meta`.

Comment: @SajibAcharya It's fine asking on either Meta.

Comment: Unable to reproduce... Huawei P8 Lite on SE Android v1.0.77.